# Create 2 types of register form laravel User/Seller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication

I would like to create 2 different register of authentication.
I will use php artisan make --auth for the users but I need an other kind of register with more inputs for sellers when they register (because i need more information from them).

I saw the possibility to add a role then redirect to another page depending the answer but I would like to have also 2 different table

1 Create_Users_Table
2 Create_Sellers_table

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What's your question about this? How is this related to MySQL?

Comment: Hello I've already had an answer but many thanks. 
Is related in the fact that you need to store sellers and users registration in DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using hesto/auth package. https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth

```sh
composer require hesto/multi-auth
```

```sh
php artisan multi-auth:install admin -f 
php artisan multi-auth:install seller -f
```

In laravel we are already using users table for authentication so that's why you also need to make sellers table authentication.

```sh
php artisan multi-auth:install seller -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you man!

It works. The only problem is route are different:

with the package we have :
http://127.0.0.1:8000/**seller**/register

and Laravel users is only:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/register

So to keep a same structure I've to do also php artisan multi-auth:install user -f
like this i can have somethink like:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/**user**/register